# Frame GoBack Event with parameter

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I'm building an XAML Metro app using C# and having some thoughts.
I'm using two pages, MainPage and OtherPage.

When i click a button in MainPage i go to the other one with

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(OtherPage), AndAnObjectIsSentTo);
```

To go back from OtherPage to MainPage, i have a (cancel) button with the code `Frame.GoBack();`

What i want to achieve when i go back is to send a parameter and (EDIT: not "reload" but just run a function) the MainPage (the page i get back to). How should I do this?

Answer (score 3):

GoBack doesn't pass a parameter so you'll need to pass the data through an outside channel.

One possibility would be to include it as a property in the object passed to Frame.Navigate. The original page can track what it sent and then look up what it had sent when OnNavigatedTo is called with NavigationMode.Back.

Also consider that complex objects aren't recommended for the parameter in [Frame.Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh702394.aspx) since only simple types support navigation state serialization. A typical alternative is to pass a string or GUID key into a lookup table. This table could also be used to store return values back.

Lastly, if the pages share a data model you could store the data there, though you may not want to muddle your data with command parameters.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answer. When you say complex, what do you think of then? I have different object which i serialize in files. I load the object in the first form, pass it to the second and then pass it back. You think it's better to send the filename to load the object from? That is, load object in form one, tell form 2, "read this file", read it, save the changes to file and then, then on form .navigatedto() (or something) read the file. i still need to till form 1 which file to read? i could store it as a setting, maybe?

Answer (score -2):

You can always go back with the Navigate method to the previous page the same way you got there. And then you can pass a parameter, too.

Will that not work for you?

Comment: no, that creates an additional entry in die BackStack